# Intershop: Is there a way to read value from properties file in an ISML?

Tags: intershop

What would be the suggested approach to read property value from properties file in an ISML?

Comment: This question is way too broad for a precise answer. How would you evaluate an approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on one where your property file is. If you put it to `/staticfiles/cartridge/config`: Yes!

You can access the configuration object from the domain:

```
#CurrentDomain:Configuration:String("My.Config.Key")#
```